# Visual Studio 2019 (16.11.5) clickonce publish succeeds but clickonce is not packaged and pushed to network share

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, clickonce, .net-5

I have a winforms application that had click once working in visual studio.  after the recent update to 16.11.5, the exact same publish profile for the clickonce app is no longer working after updating from an earlier version of visual studio.

Anywhere I should check for changes to click once?  this is really baffeling and my google skills seem to be failing me in finding an issue.

The only output I get from the publish (build output log) is that the publish succeeded.  The files are being published to the staging publish folder and I have made sure I have full permissions on the network share configured for the user install location.

Comment: Maybe the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/framework/clickonce-application-fails-update) would help you.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT the issue is publishing not updating on the client side.  I did see that but if the click once files are never pushed to the unc path on publish, the user can’t even get to the point of trying to install from the unc path.